# how to notify the main thread when Redisson failed to renew a lock?

Tags: java, redis, locking, redisson, distributed-lock

In the implementation of the watchdog in Redisson, if the renewal fails, it will just release the lock and do nothing:

[image]

That means the main thread doesn't know if it has lost the lock and will continue its relevant process. This may lead to inconsistency or non-idempotent.

How to solve this situation?